# What does the "I" stand for in the QtCreator API for classes such as "IRunConfigurationFactory", "IFile", "IProjectManager"?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

What does the "I" stand for in the QtCreator API for classes such as "IRunConfigurationFactory", "IFile", "IProjectManager", etc?

What does this indicate to the person who looks to use the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An uppercase "I" usually stands for "Interface". I'm not sure if that is the case here, but it would make sense to me.

Comment: I presume that "Interface" is thus intended for me to interact with it, that I should interface with this class?

Comment: From IRC : <andre_> I* is not really deprecated, it's just that creator got less "interfacy" over time
<andre_> some of the I* were needless abstractions, in some cases plain value classes turned out to make more sense.

Comment: Well as a developer, the whole API is there to be used by you, but in Object Oriented Programming (Qt is written in C++, which is object oriented) "Interface" refers to a completely abstract class, i.e. a class that defines methods without implementing them. That allows Qt, for example, to return instances of completely different classes from the same method, as long as those classes implement the interface which is set as return type of the function. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a good page on the web explaining what an interface (OOP) is.